# How to install crossover-pro from CD

Tags: 12.04

I like to install crossover-pro_9.0.1-1_i386.deb from CD in Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried to install from gdebi package manager but package manager showing error message "cannot install python:i386 "
Pl. help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to your CD drive, and run the command below.

```
sudo dpkg -i < package_name.deb >
```

I would recommend running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` prior to installing.

Comment: Do you recommend also actually upgrading installed packages to newer available versions (for example, with `sudo apt-get upgrade` after `sudo apt-get update`), or are you just suggesting running `sudo apt-get update` so that information about package dependencies is up to date when the `.deb` package is manually installed?